# Pass array as query string

Tags: javascript, json, query-string

I'm attempting to pass an array to my server via jsonp - here's a JSON example of what I'm trying to pass:

```
["something","another_thing",4,{"iam" : "anobject"}]
```

However, I'm not sure how (if it's possible) to pass an array.

I assumed it would be like this:

```
something&another_thing&4&[iam]=anobject
```

but when I pass that to `querystring.parse()` in node, it gives me this:

```
{ '4': '',
  something: '',
  another_thing: '',
  '[iam]': 'anobject' }
```

That's definitely not what I want. I can just use JSON, but this is now something I'm wondering if is possible.

Comment: did you try to use JSON.stringify ?

Comment: I've already implemented this in my code using JSON - this is just a curiosity about what can be passed via GET queries.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to pass that data structure using PHP's URI format (which is what your attempt looks like), it would look something like:

```
data[0]=something&data[1]=another_thing&data[2]=4&data[3][iam]=anobject
```

You are probably better off just passing the JSON itself though. Take the JavaScript object and run it through `JSON.stringify()` and `encodeURIComponent()` to get:

```
data=something%2Canother_thing%2C4%2C%5Bobject%20Object%5D
```

Then you would use `querystring.parse()`, extract the `data` parameter from it, then run `JSON.parse()` on that value.

Comment: As I said in the post - I can just use JSON (in fact I am), but I was mostly just curious to see if there was a way to pass an array as a root object on a query.